# Is "message" a reserved word in Django or Python?

Tags: python, django

I seem to get a TypeError ('message' is an invalid keyword argument for this function) every time I try adding something in the DB via the Django admin interface. The object is added but this exception is raised. Could be this linked to the fact that I have a model named "Message"?

Comment: Could you post a traceback please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Python's reserved words do not include message and the TypeError you've described doesn't suggest a namespace collision. Look at the function's keyword arguments and make sure that `message` is among them. It isn't though, so maybe you meant to type `msg`.

Comment: the thing is I get this for any function that adds objects in the DB

Comment: @adrianp - that means that none of these functions have a `message` keyword argument.

Answer (score 3):

When trying to assign a value to reserved keywords, SyntaxError is raised.

Answer (score 1):

That means the function you are calling does not accept an argument named "message".

I guess that's because the model your are using doesn't have a field named "message"

Answer (score 1):

This example shows what others have already pointed out.

```
>>> def hello(msg):
...     print "Hello, ", msg    
... 
>>> hello("world")
Hello,  world
>>> hello(msg="world")
Hello,  world
>>> hello(message="world")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: hello() got an unexpected keyword argument 'message'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was missing the directives for the [Django messages framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) in my settings.py. Thanks anyway for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe message | messages is a reserved word! The following is my code snippet:

```
messages = page.object_list
variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'messages': messages,
    'show_paginator': paginator.num_pages > 1,
    'has_prev': page.has_previous(),
    'has_next': page.has_next(),
    'page': page_number,
    'pages': paginator.num_pages,
    'next_page': page_number + 1,
    'prev_page': page_number - 1 
})
return render_to_response('user_page.html', variables)
```

The problem occurs when I check for the messages list in user_page.html. For whatever reason, the check, {% if messages %}, will always return false, even if the list is populated.The minute I changed variable names it worked as intended. I haven't found any documentation backing this up, all I know is that I banged my head for 1.5 days till randomly figuring it out.